# VBA Ubound Arrays or Subarrays

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a "results" array that stores various data in results(0) results(1), results(2) and results(3). The problem that I am having is that I cannot figure out the Ubound of results(0). VBa gives me Ubound of Results as being 3, but I need the Ubound of Results(0) and I cant seem to find a way to get that. If you take a look at the screenshot below it looks like this time around there are 9-10 items stored in results(0). How can I get VBA to get Ubound number 10 for all the variations under results (0) (which are results(0,1)...al the way to results(0,10). How do I do this?

Array I'm looking to Ubound

[image]

I even tried this but it did not work:

```
        For X = LBound(results0) To UBound(results0) ''''''''''give me an error on Ubound(results0)
        
        Next X
```

Answer (score 2):

The array is call `results` you would do:

```
Ubound(results,2)
```

to get the upper bound of the 2nd dimension.

Then to call that specific you would use `results(0,x)`

```
For X = LBound(results,2) To UBound(results,2)
    Debug.Print results(0,x)
Next X
```